# Android - Insert large text in an Activity

Tags: android, text, hyperlink, textview

i need to create an activity with the description on an object.

This description is about 1000 characters, on 16 line.

I wanna ask if there is some way or some rule to follow to insert a string big like this in a textview in android?

I only have to format in in the values/string file or i have to do something else?

And in this description there are some link, how can make them clickable? (when i click i wanna  open my browser with the link).

Answer (score 1):

To make links clickable just add this to your view :

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

Yes you just need to add that text to resources.

Best wishes.

Comment: with:

android:autoLink="web"

the link is not clickable!

i have made:

TextView Testo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtCompanyProfile);

 Testo.setText(Html.fromHtml("Ttxt text text<br/> " +
       "text text text<br/>" +
       "<a href=\"http://www.google.it\">Per maggiori informazioni cliccare qui</a>"));

Answer (score 0):

Put the string in strings.xml, set it to a text view inside a scroll view so that it doesn't get hidden on smaller screens, set [autoLink](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aautoLink) to make the links clickable.

Comment: i've resolved, for making the link clickable, in this way:



myTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());